# template event to display one document from a collection at a time?

Tags: meteor

Given this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Players.find().count() === 0) {
      var names = ["Ada Lovelace", "Grace Hopper", "Marie Curie",
                   "Carl Friedrich Gauss", "Nikola Tesla", "Claude Shannon"];
      _.each(names, function (name) {
        Players.insert({
          name: name,
          score: Math.floor(Random.fraction() * 10) * 5
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

How do I write a template event to display one name at a time with a button to click that will iterate through the rest of the list?

Comment: Like pagination essentially? You could probably do this with: https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Collection you are iterating over won't change, or you don't need to handle those data changes you can do something like this :

working example
http://meteorpad.com/pad/89r8ZKR8M5fHLCyx5/IterateStaticData

```
// store some local state here for your iteration
var currentIndex = 0;
var myPlayers;
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click #iterateNames' : function(){
    currentIndex++;
      // only load the data once
    if(!myPlayers){
      myPlayers = Players.find({}).fetch();
    }
    if(currentIndex===myPlayers.length){
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    var currentPlayer = myPlayers[currentIndex];
    Session.set("nextPlayer",currentPlayer);
  }
});
```

If the Collection you are iterating over does change, and you need to handle those data changes you can do something like this :

working example
http://meteorpad.com/pad/3aEjv5HaGPzSDcvKY/IterateDynamicData

```
var found = [];  // people we've found in this iteration loop

function findNext(){
  var queryNext = {_id:{$nin:found}};
  return Players.findOne(queryNext);
}

Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click #iterateNames' : function(){

    var nextPlayer = findNext();
    if(nextPlayer){
      found.push(nextPlayer._id);
    }
    if(!nextPlayer){
      found = [];
      nextPlayer = findNext();
      found.push(nextPlayer._id);
    }

    // do something with the next item
    someDomElement.innerHTML = nextPlayer.name;

})
```

while the meteorpad example app seems to display the order consistently upon iteration, I think there is no guarantee of that order.   If anyone can elaborate on that it would be interesting.

Comment: I used the IterateStaticData above, (much thanks) but how do I get the first document in the array to load when I first run the program? The names iterate starting with the second document when I click the "Click to Iterate Names" button.

Comment: My test code here:  (http://meteorpad.com/pad/KjvQJQHzbZFkh7gyJ/IterateProverbsTest)

Comment: you can put the iteration routine into a function, and then call it when the Template first renders, in addition to the mouse click event.    in this case, I recommend to use a server method to just return the items.  updated the meteor pad :  http://meteorpad.com/pad/89r8ZKR8M5fHLCyx5/IterateStaticData

Comment: the reason for using the server method is a long discussion.  You can do the same thing without the server method, see David Weldon's explanation "Subscriptions don't block" here https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes ,   he shows some alternative ways to get the array on the client, and he provides a good explanation about data latency in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you can write

@yourTemplate

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
  {{#each players}}
     {{name}} - {{score}}
  {{/each}}
  <button class="add-player">Add Player</button>
</template>
```

@yourJSFile

```
//We set default value at Session variable numberOfPlayers
Template.yourTemplate.created = function () {
  Session.setDefault("numberOfPlayers",1);
}

//We set a helper which return players at template
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  players: function () {
    return Players.find({}, {limit:Session.get("numberOfPlayers")});
  }
});

//When you click at button just add one at Session variable and that triggers the helper to return the next player
Template.yourTemplate.events({
   "click .add-player": function (event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var numOfPlayers = Session.get("numberOfPlayers");
      Sessionl.set("numberOfPlayers", numOfPlayers+1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this night not be the answer you are looking for but unfortunately meteor doesn't support (yet) mongoDB's `cursor.hasNext()` and `cursor.next()` functions. Otherwise you could do something like that in you template events code:

```js
  var players;

  Template.leaderboard.created = function(){
    players = null;
  }

  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click .next': function () {
      if(players.hasNext()){
        players.next();
      }
    }
  }
```

It supports though the `cursor.forEach()` method. What are you trying to achieve in detail? I'm sure there is a workable solution for your use case just let us know more details.

Comment: I want to build a small "flashcards"-like app for my students. It displays a single paragraph-ish amount of info. When they are done reading, they hit the NEXT button until they are through. They do not edit or create new flashcards.

Comment: @LanceBarker  in that case I'd recommend just calling "fetch" on the collection, store it in an array, and keep track of the current card.   I would only recommend doing this type of "hasNext()" iteration if cards are added or removed from the database while the user is looping through them.