# Loop through Meteor collection cursor without forEach

Tags: meteor

I've got a cursor returned from a collection with ~220 entries built in the following way:

```
var readers = Readers.find({
    groupId: groupId,
    readerHWId: { $exists: true }
}, {
    reactive: false
});
```

I want to make an ajax request for each of these entries, but I want to do them in sequence, so I can't use .forEach().  Is there an alternative to extracting an entry based on an index that I can maintain myself?  I understand Meteor doesn't have .hasNext() and .next(), so I'm wondering if there's some way I can manage how I loop through these items asynchronously myself.  I tried .fetch() and I get "process out of memory" (I'm on windows 8, not sure if that's related).

Comment: fetch() should work unless your documents are huge ?    You can mimic hasNext using a technique here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735098/template-event-to-display-one-document-from-a-collection-at-a-time/28736145#28736145 .   Also, if you store an ordinal index field on each of your mongo documents, you can query them by your index.

Comment: @looshi is right that you can just put the index into the documents themselves and then just *sort* in the *find()*. If your documents are large then just restrict your *find()* to only return specific fields and do at *fetch()*.